# Contact Person APEX

Tags: apex

Hello I would like to understand how to get contact without the person account

I tried to do it like this:

```
List<contact> getCon = new List<contact>([Select Id from contact where ISPERSONACCOUNT = false)];
```

but it still give's me the output that include person account in salesforce

Answer (score 1):

I run this query in my org and it works fines and give me correct result. Make sure you are checking correct record. The only issue which I can see right now is syntax error (Change the bracket order).

```
List<contact> getCon = new List<contact>([Select Id from contact where ISPERSONACCOUNT = false]);
```

Comment: It should work.. Note that you don't even need the explicit constructor for the list, you can just assign the query.

Comment: Hello I tried that one but the thing is it give me the records of person customer

Comment: @JohnJones Can you share screenshot of query result and related record.